# Why does the color picker in Photoshop CS6 allow eight characters instead of six?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Why does the color picker in Photoshop CS6 allow eight characters instead of six?  Further, is there a way to cap it at six characters like earlier versions of Photoshop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the RGB color model, the two additional characters allow you to copy and paste extra characters such as the `#` or `0x` prefix to [hexadecimal color codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Hex_triplet). As for the possibility of limiting the input length to six characters, perhaps someone else with access to the program could chime in.

Comment: Confirmed - http://forums.adobe.com/thread/982436?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Wow that's annoying.  Will accept this answer at some point but still holding out hope that someone can come swoop in with a way to move the cap back to six.  Thanks.